# Unable to execlude packages from code analysis

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I am using Spring Boot JPA example and in the pom.xml we've configured to completely exclude the packages to to be removed during static code analysis.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <sonar.exclusions>
        **/enums/**/*,**/entity/**/*,**/constant/**/*,**/dto/**/*,**/repository/**/*
    </sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.test.exclusions>**/test/**</sonar.test.exclusions>
</properties>
```

But we've seen that these packages are not getting excluded. Any pointers why ?

Comment: Where die you put the sonar.exclusions in the pom.xml?

Comment: Its under `<properties>` tag

Comment: Do you see any output like  [INFO] Excluded sources:
[INFO]   **/dto/**/*
[INFO]   **/repository/**/*

Answer (score 0):

Follow this procedure to exclude these packages:
**Click on your project name in SonarQube -> Administration -> General Settings -> Analysis Scope -> Source File Exclusions** (You can put the file pattern in the text box)

This will skip the files which matches the given pattern.